# Probability of collision of brownian particles

Tags: brownian-motion, randomness

2 Brownian particles in a volume $V$. I wish to compute the probability that a collision occurs during a time $dt$. This should be a function of $V$ and the diffusion coefficient $D$.

The result should be at large time, so independent of the initial conditions.

I cannot figure out what the first steps should be. In particular what blocks me is that the particles are in a box, so the density is conserved.

Comment: What exactly to you mean by density probability?

Comment: Sorry that was unclear. I just edited, I hope its better. The probability that a collision occurs during a time dt